# How to set serial ports uart to none for lirc?

Tags: 11.04, lirc

lirc_serial won't load because the serial port is already in use.
dmesg reports

```
[   12.245857] lirc_serial: port 03f8 already in use
[   12.245862] lirc_serial: use 'setserial /dev/ttySX uart none'
```

back in the days I used to edit a file called /var/lib/setserial/autoserial.conf or /etc/serial.conf to set UART to none on the corresponding serial port. The first doesn't help and the later doesn't exist no more.

All the Howtos and threads on message boards concerning LIRC are from the stoneage.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Could you confirm if one of the answers worked, and mark it as answered please?

Answer (score 2):

You can create /etc/serial.conf and put lines like

```
/dev/ttyS0 uart none
```

into it. `/etc/init.d/etc-setserial` reads this file. The `setserial` binary is part of the setserial package, which is a dependency of the lirc package, so it should be automatically installed.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work when you load it manually?

```
sudo modprobe lirc_serial
```

Check your */etc/lirc/hardware.conf* for those lines:

```
REMOTE_MODULES="lirc_serial"
LOAD_MODULES="true"
```

I've had have the same problem and this solved it.